# Do you lose functionality when hosting ASP.NET MVC on IIS 6? If so, what?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, iis-6

As a dev team, we're looking to switch to asp.net MVC and I've heard rumors about IIS 6 not being able to support all of the MVC functionality.  Is this true?  Is there any official set of functionality supported in IIS 7 vs IIS 6?  Should we completely avoid running it on IIS6?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do not loose any functionality of ASP.Net MVC; however, you have one of two options. You can either define an extension on your URL's which will allow you to set up mapping. So for example:

> www.example.com/books/computer/list

might become:

> www.example.com/books.mvc/computer/list

You can use any extension you want so long as you map to ASP.Net. I am currently using .aspx which meant I could avoid changing IIS configuration at the sacrifice of having extensionless URLs.

The other option as mentioned is using a wild card mapping. What this does is route all requests to ASP.Net. Even requests for static content such as images. This does have a negative effect on performance that you will want to measure. There are ways around this, I believe such as placing all your content in a specific virtual directory that you turn off the wild card mapping for, but I haven't fully explored that option.

Comment: I think IIS7 Integrated mode can also have this performance issue as it routes everything to ASP.NET. It's not IIS6 specific.

Comment: I'd hope they'd have optimized the pipeline for that but couldnt say. time to hit google

Answer (score 5):

I think the issue with IIS6 is extensionless URLs that you can easily achieve by adding a wildcard ISAPI map in IIS configuration.

So, no. While I love IIS7 integrated mode and strongly recommend using it, you won't lose functionality using it. I've deployed several ASP.NET MVC 1.0 projects on Windows Server 2003/IIS6.

Comment: We use IIS6 for our production site and this is the only real side-effect we have noticed.

Comment: So, no loss in functionality?  Just more initial configuration involved?

Comment: This is the only thing I've ever seen and heard in this regard and considering what I know about ASP.NET and IIS in general, this is the only logical one.

Answer (score 1):

Url rewriting can help you to solve the problem. I've implemented solution allowing to deploy MVC application at any IIS version even when virtual hosting is used.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/iis-aspnet-url-rewriting.aspx