# IIS7.0 to IIS6.0

Tags: .net-3.5, iis-7, c#-3.0, iis-6, web-config

So after months of work I load the project on the clients computers after months of them assuring me they run windows server 2008.

It's not is 2003 and so IIS6.0.

Does anyone have an easy way to downgrade my web.config to IIS6.0?

currently I get Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'type'.

sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture

Comment: You're in for a lot of work.  Make sure your clients pay you for what is clearly THEIR mistake (stating the wrong runtime environment to develop a solution on).

Comment: How is this a lot of work?  This is a framework issue, not IIS.  Install 3.5 and be done with it.  web.configs are not "iis version specific"

Answer (score 9):

Is it possible to upgrade their machine to the latest .NET 3.5 site?  Because a IIS 7.0 web.config can run on IIS 6.0 with out any changes, you just need to have .NET 3.5 running on the IIS 6 site.  However if your whole application is compiled against .NET 3.5, the upgrade of the framework is a requirement, unless you want to rewrite your whole app for .NET 2.0.

Comment: This is what you need, install .net 3.5

Answer (score 3):

Is this an IIS or a framework issue? Seems to me like you just have to install .NET 3.5 on their box and voila you are the hero

Answer (score 1):

The only potential issue you may have is if you wrote the application using MVC or System.web.routing. Even then, there are hacks to get that working in IIS6.

Comment: Yup, see my question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752830/do-you-lose-functionality-when-hosting-asp-net-mvc-on-iis-6-if-so-what

Answer (score 1):

Set the Framework version in your application to 2.0.50727.

Answer (score 0):

No this is an IIS not framework issue.  As you can see from my post above.  The web.config that has been generated for IIS7 will not work with IIS6.

There are tags that IIS6 doesn't know about plus IIS7 web.config puts things like handlers in sections that IIS6 doesn't know about.

I needed a quick way to regenerate the web.config for the project that was compatible with IIS6.  I've edited it by hand now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article that discusses how to setup a web.config file that will work on both IIS6 and IIS7.

http://arcware.net/use-a-single-web-config-for-iis6-and-iis7/